# How does Batch Normalization not lead to the model blowing up?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, batch-normalization

I was reading the [Batch Norm paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) and in this paragraph,

> We could consider whitening activations at every training step or at
>   some interval, either by modifying the network directly or by changing
>   the parameters of the optimization algorithm to depend on the network
>   activation values (Wiesler et al., 2014; Raiko et al., 2012; Povey et
>   al., 2014; Desjardins & Kavukcuoglu). However, if these modifications
>   are interspersed with the optimization steps, then the gradient
>   descent step may attempt to update the parameters in a way that
>   requires the normalization to be updated, which reduces the effect of
>   the gradient step. For example, consider a layer with the input $u$ that
>   adds the learned bias $b$, and normalizes the result by subtracting the
>   mean of the activation computed over the training data: $\hat{x} = x − E[x]$
>   where $x = u + b$, $\mathcal{X} = \{x_{1 \ldots N} \}$ is the set of values of $x$ over he
>   training set, and $E[x] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$ . If a gradient descent step
>   ignores the dependence of $E[x]$ on $b$, then it will update $b \leftarrow b + \Delta b$,
>   where $\Delta b \propto −\partial l/ \partial \hat{x}$. Then $u + (b + \Delta b) − E[u + (b + \Delta b)] = u + b − E[u + b]$. Thus, the combination of the update to $b$ and subsequent change in normalization led to no change in the output of the layer nor,
>   consequently, the loss. As the training continues, $b$ will grow
>   indefinitely while the loss remains fixed. This problem can get worse
>   if the normalization not only centers but also scales the activations.
>   We have observed this empirically in initial experiments, where the
>   model blows up when the normalization parameters are computed outside
>   the gradient descent step.

What's the point of having $b$ anyway? (Later in the paper, it says that b is removed during batch normalization, so what's the aim of the math shown in this picture and how is this* math different from the one that we do during actual batch normalization).

This happens later in the paper,

> Note that, since we normalize Wu+b, the bias b can be ignored since
>   its effect will be canceled by the subsequent mean subtraction (the
>   role of the bias is subsumed by β in Alg. 1). Thus, z = g(Wu + b) is
>   replaced with z = g(BN(Wu))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation comes in the next paragraph. Instead of normalizing by the mean of activations in a single batch, they normalize with respect to the whole training data ($\mathcal{X}$). The way they achieve this is by using moving averages that get updated for each mini-batch during training.

The reason why the bias term becomes redundant is due to learned scale and shift variables $\gamma^{(k)}$, and $\beta^{(k)}$. Without these, the normalization would squash everything which could limit what a non-linearity activation function can represent. They give the example of the sigmoid activation function which would be constraint to the linear part only and the tails would be squashed.